# host to docker directory mount error

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am getting this error while mounting host directory to docker container.

```
$ docker run -v $pwd:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ -it xampp bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume spec ":/opt/lampp/htdocs/": invalid volume specification: ':/opt/lampp/htdocs/'.
  See 'docker run --help'.
```

Inside docker `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` exists :

Please help.

Comment: Try `$PWD` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> $docker run -v $PWD:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ -it xampp bash

docker use bash internal `$PWD` [Check Here](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/6f812a4ec18453dd0f46e138f7c05b1ade13f007)